# Where to put Google API key

Tags: api, google-maps

I made a styled map in Google Maps and I needed an API key to make it work. I did it, and it workes fine if the API key is not restricted. If I restrict it on a particular IP or domain, it doesn't work, but this is not the problem I want to discuss here. I was wondering, why not leaving my key unrestricted? So i searched online and [they said](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037?hl=it) that a key shouldn't be unrestricted for security reasons, so they suggest to

> store them in environment variables or in files outside of your application's source tree

I asked myself then, even if I put my API key in an external file, get it with php or whatever, wouldn't it be shown in the html's source code anyway? I mean, in the [how-to](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) page they say to write this code

> ```
>  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
> ```

that's fine, but whatever is my way to set the **YOUR_API_KEY**, whether getting it from an external file or not, it will be shown on my html's source code anyway.

So,

- does anyone know what they mean when they say to put the API key on an external file?
- If i find a way to put it on an external file, can I leave it unrestricted? If so, what could happen (speeching from a security point of view)?

Answer (score 1):

Leaving an API completely unrestricted is awful practice and should be avoided in almost every situation. All someone with malicious intent needs to do is find your API key and suddenly they have access to almost everything function that the API key gives you access to. Always restrict keys to the bare minimum.

Since you're going to be embedding the map into an iframe, that script is going to be run client side meaning there isn't much when it comes to hiding the API key but if you restrict a key to simply view maps (and any other functions that will be needed on the users side) there won't be any need to hide it and you can leave it in there as the docs show you.

The document you read on best practices for security with API's applies more to applications of the Google API where it is handling sensitive data or the key has access to functions that could seriously compromise the security of your application if accessed. This doesn't apply in the scenario you described with maps.